# Return header when call sign_in of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want return the header with (access_token,uid and client) when calling sign_in

```
 promoter = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
   res = sign_in(promoter)
   puts(res.headers)
```

this get error

```
    "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `headers' for #<User:0x000055a21fabacb8>>",
```

Comment: What do you mean by return header?

Comment: when call sign_in devise ,it returns header with (access-token,uid and client of this user